# app crashing when changing text of a cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with a `PrototypeCell`, which has a few `Labels` that I want modify after the `CollectionView` is loaded. I add the outlets for the `Labels` in a subclass like other stackoverflow questions suggest, and when I run the app  it `crashes`. Why is this happening?

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsZWD.png)

[subclass image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGl8T.png)

Comment: Would you post a code causing the errors?

Comment: place a breakpoint and see the code that generates the error. and post it here.

Comment: Don't post screenshot, copy/past code/logs.

Answer (score 0):

Have another derived class which inherits from UICollectionViewCell and create the outlets in this new derived class. Make sure your outlet references are weak.

Now, from the subclass of UICollectionViewController override the following (swift):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: REUSABLE_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! YourCollectionViewCell
}
```

where YourCollectionViewCell is your own class specialised for the cell you created. You need to provide an identifier for your cell template.

Further you can use this cell to access the property or method you will create in YourCollectionViewCell. You can even access the label outlet here as well.

Comment: I was just working with my program and found out that the outlet was not connected. I connected and the app started to crash again. I have already put the outlets in a subclass like the answer above says to do. @Kajal Sinha

Comment: it looks like you missed out assigning the identifier to your cell in storyboard view. as I said in answer please provide an identifier to your cell template.

Comment: I was just looking at the error message in detail and found at the top it says: Unknown class NAMEOFTHECLASS in Interface Builder file. Is there a way to fix this? I think this may be the reason the app is crashing. @Kajal Sinha

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "InterestsCollectionViewCell",
>   bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
>   "(InterestsCollectionViewCell.self)")

when you are registering the cell register with nib and identifier